# PHP - WAMP server

Tags: php, wamp

I have a problem with WAMP server (2.1); I have some php files that contain php statements between

```
<? statements ?>
```

and the browser don't interprets the code. If I use :

```
<?php statements ?>
```

everything works ok.

Any idea how to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether you *should* or *should not* use short tags is debatable. I personally do not and I don’t recommend it. That being said — with WAMPServer 2 you can:

1. Click on the wampserver tray icon.
2. Go to **PHP**. Then **PHP Settings**
3. Click **short open tag**. (When it's on it will have a
   checkmark next to it.)

Using the tray icon (lower right — next to the clock) is the easiest, least error prone way to make *any* changes in WAMPServer 2+.

Comment: Well said.  I do use short open tags, and haven't seen a convincing case on why I shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

As kieran said:

> This is a good thread on why you shouldn't use short tags: [Are PHP
>   short tags acceptable to use?](http://This%20is%20a%20good%20thread%20on%20why%20you%20shouldn%27t%20use%20short%20tags%3a%20Are%20PHP%20short%20tags%20acceptable%20to%20use?)

**If you decided to used them**, add in your php.ini:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

[Documentation for php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

---

Be carefull, in a wamp installation, php.ini can be found at multiple locations:

```
wamp\bin\apache\Apache<version>\bin\php.ini
wamp\bin\php\php<version>\php.ini
```

Accessing the php.ini from the wamp menu (left click on `wamp tray icon` / `php` / `php.ini`) opens the php.ini of the current apache version.

Comment: You should do the modification manually in the php.ini in the `wamp\bin\php\php<version>\php.ini` folder

Comment: -1: although not yet deprecated there's enough debate over short_open_tags to suggest that using the full php tags is a better solution. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413661/php6-is-short-open-tag-removed-or-deprecated-or-neither

Answer (score 1):

This is a good thread on why you **shouldn't** use short tags: [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Don't use `<? statements ?>` - short tags are evil!

You can change it in the php.ini file but it even says in that file not to use them...

> This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code
>   between  tags as PHP source which should be processed as
>   such. It's been recommended for several years that you not use the
>   short tag "short cut" and instead to use the full  tag
>   combination. With the wide spread use of XML and use of these tags
>   by other languages, the server can become easily confused and end up
>   parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. But because this short
>   cut has been a feature for such a long time, it's currently still ;
>   supported for backwards compatibility, but we recommend you don't use them.  Default Value: On ; Development
>   Value: Off ; Production Value: Off ;
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Agreed, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I didn't answer the question for a reason, that there is a good chance that further down the line this will be a bigger problem. I said you can change it in the php.ini file - but I wanted to raise the bigger issue that and not just give instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Once again, I agree with you, _as most competent developers probably will_. However, isn't it better to make this commentary within the context of an answer. "you can change it in the php.ini file" is hardly an answer.